# The GET HTTP request sent from Angular is causing 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, passport.js

I am trying to send a GET request to the server, such that is the user at the login phase is authenticated, they can access a certain route. Otherwise, they cannot. This route is `/user`. My problem is that whenever the login is successful the user still does not gain access to the route `/user`. I have created a middleware function which checks if the user is authenticated:

```
function isValidUser(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) next();
  else return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized Request" });
}
```

This middleware function was then used in the user route:

```
router.get("/user", isValidUser, function(req, res, next) {
  return res.status(200).json(req.user);
});
```

Now for Angular, I was sending the requests in the services as follows:

```
  user() {
    return this._http.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/user", {
      observe: "body",
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append("Content-Type", "application/json")
    });
  }
```

Finally, inside the component which should be made accessible to the user, I injected this service in the constructor

```
constructor(private _user: UserService, private _router: Router) {
    this._user.user().subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this._router.navigate(["/login"]);
      }
    );
  }
```

Here is the cors configurations in the server:

```
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:4200", "http://127.0.0.1:4200"],
    credentials: true
  })
);
```

The error I am getting when I try to login is:

```
 GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/user 500 (Internal Server Error)
user:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/user' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: you need to enable cors on your backend

Comment: also for the frontend i would look into using an authgaurd and can activate

Comment: @PariBaker I already have cors added on my backend. I modified my question

Comment: try changing your `origin` property to a string of `*` instead of an array

Comment: The fact that you’re getting a 500 response has absolutely nothing to do with whether or not you have the server CORS-enabled — at least not unless you have some syntax error in your CORS-configuration code. But at least there’s no syntax error in the CORS-configuration code shown in the question — so you can rule that out as having anything to do with the cause of the 500 error. And just like any other case when somebody is getting a 500 error, there’s basically nothing anybody here can do from our side to identify the actual cause. We could only guess/speculate.

Comment: The only troubleshooting option you have in this case is to check the logs on the server side of the server which the request is being sent to. Look for whatever messages the server is logging there prior to the server sending the 500 response. You’re the only one among us here who has access to those logs…

Answer (score 0):

```js
// alternatively without using external packages just paste this in your code before your routes

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT"
  );

  next();
});
```

Comment: umm who downvoted this? I'm offering an alternative to using cors() that I am sure works